# maven dependency range does not work as expected

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, range

Maven 2.2.1 claims to support version ranges (see e.g. http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges)

I tried from a brandnew maven installation the following pom:

```
<project>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>rangetest</artifactId>
  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <description>test project containing one dependency, only</description>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </project>
```

The dependency should resolve to junit 4.8.2, right?
But instead, the version 4.8 is resolved:

```
C:\Users>mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'dependency'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - my.group:rangetest:jar:1.0
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] my.group:rangetest:jar:1.0
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.8:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 07 14:30:40 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/23M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You might think it's an issue with Junit, as 4.8 is an existing version, but it's not. In my projects, I have versions deployed from 1.0.0 to 1.0.15 (no version 1.0!), but `mvn dependency:tree` complains about missing artifact of version 1.0.

Answer (score 8):

That only works if you actually specify a version range *or* if you have more than one POM. You use `4.8` which is a single version number, so Maven tries to resolve it directly. A version range must start with `[` or `(` (inclusive and exclusive, respectively).

In your case, try: `[4.8,4.9)`

That should give you the highest version with the same API (i.e. all bug fixes but no breaking changes).

This document shows how Maven interprets versions: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html

The first line seems to support your position (`4.8` means "at least 4.8") but there is a catch: Maven will only select a higher version if anyone specifically asks for it. So unless you have more POMs in your build and one of those asks for `4.8.2`, `4.8` is "good enough" for Maven.

Think of it as a hint for conflict resolution. If POM A asks for 4.8 and B asks for 4.8.2 **and** B depends on A, then Maven has to make a decision. Should it fail? Should it use 4.8? Or 4.8.2?

The rules resolve this conflict by picking 4.8.2 without giving a warning or an error.

If A asks for `[4.8]`, you'd get an error instead since Maven can't silently "upgrade" the dependency to 4.8.2 and it certainly can't downgrade 4.8.2 to 4.8.

Comment: Well, Maven range spec http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges makes a difference between "hard" requirements (e.g. [4.8]) and a "soft" requirement (like 4.8 without brackets). What's the use of soft requirements, then?

Comment: @Jay: Never heard of the term. `4.8.1` selects just that version and nothing else. My guess is that the document is outdated.

Comment: Yes, maybe another sad example for Maven's poor documentation. Do you know of any better reference for the version stuff?

Comment: soft requirements work like they should. when resolving dependencies and there is a conflict between version, the best one is choosen if at most one of them is a hard requirement. see the note at the end of the link in your question.

Comment: Maven [defines `1.0` to mean `x >= 1.0` with `1.0` preferred](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html).  So if another dependency wants a version greater than `1.0`, Maven will use the greater version to satisfy both.  But if you use `[1.0]` this is a hard requirement, and any hard dependency on a different version will be incompatible.

Comment: @CarlG: Honestly, I'm quite surprised by this document since Maven seems to behave differently. But that might be because of how I use it: I try to define each version only once (i.e. I extensively use parent POMs and `dependencyManagement` to nail down versions.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I think your answer looks good.  I think the addition of the link is good since Maven treats the requirement `1.0` specially.  Whenever investigating such version interactions, we use `mvn dependency:tree`.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use version ranges, specify a version range as others pointed out. Currently, you're not.

But my real advice would be to **not use version ranges at all**, version ranges are a bad idea for build reproducibility and the last thing you want is a build that suddenly starts to fail because of an unknown reason. Just don't, they are a bad practice (which is probably why version ranges aren't documented anymore).

Comment: (+1) here's my last vote for today :-) BTW, who made this CW and why?

Comment: agreed, unless you want to use bugfixversion automaticly. but is a pain in the ass...

Comment: @seanizer: It's either the OP (only the OP can make his own question CW) or the system after 7/8(?) edits. But in this case, it's the OP as we can see in the revision history. Probably a "mistake" but the OP is new here.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? OSGI uses version ranges all the time. Please do prove your point.

Comment: OSGi has well defined version syntax semantics ... the problem is that maven is all over the place. You can only specify ranges if you use semantic versions. Semantic versions on artifacts is less useful than the package dependencies that OSGi uses.

Comment: In an OSGi context, you need to make sure that the set of candidates to match a version range don't change. This can for example be ensured by only using immutable bundle/p2 repositories. Maven repositories are typically not immutable.

Comment: Reason for my downvote: version ranges are essential if you are using a build number as the service segment for example with continuous builds.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a range qualifier in your `version` tag. Maybe you meant to use the following to require version 4.8 or later:

```
<version>[4.8,)</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, everything was working but out of the sudden I got this error

```
No versions are present in the repository for the artifact with a range [x,y)
```

I went to the library location inside `.m2/repository` folder and deleted the whole folder,

if you removed folder of a specific version of the lib it won't work, should remove folders of all versions of that lib

one more thing, if the lib is transitive you might need to remove all libraries in the dependency path

hope this helps you