# Another maven dependency range not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, managed

I know this is a much discussed topic. There are severals pages with happy and sad endings.

I've read:

1. [maven-dependency-range-does-not-work-as-expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881694/maven-dependency-range-does-not-work-as-expected)
2. [maven-version-ranges-do-not-behave-as-expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083418/maven-version-ranges-do-not-behave-as-expected)
3. [Maven Version Range References](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855)
4. [Legit but Useless: Maven Version Ranges Explained](https://michakutz.medium.com/legit-but-useless-maven-version-ranges-explained-d4ba66ac654)

All of these articles seems to talk about Hardcoded versions.
What if the version is managed ? e.g: **Sprigboot**

Using the property

```
<maven-javadoc-plugin.version>[3.4.1)</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
```

To override SpringBoot's one will result in a failure since it will try to use even ranges characters are version identifier attached image will show what I meant, and what maven is trying to do:

[image: Maven Range unrecognized evidence]

Comment: First the linked reference "Maven Version Range References" is not the reference (it is for Maven 2 meaning also extreme old) second it's from Oracle and not from Apache Maven. Furthermore to clean things up https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2017/02/2017-02-04-apache-maven-how-version-comparison-works/ Furthermore ranges do only work for dependencies but **NOT** for Plugins also I strongly recommend **NOT** to use version ranges at all. Also check https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#dependency-version-requirement-specification

Comment: I agree with you that ranges sucks and should be avoided but that is another not the topic.

Even If I was looking at  oracle's documentations I couldn't find any difference in the sintax, so.. who cares.


I don't get what makes plugin's versions different from any other dependency version. I don't have time to test this right now.


What I'm interested is for a way to override SpringBoot BOM versions WITHOUT having to HARD-CODE a specific version, which is what springboot does and I don't want to. 

Is there a way ?

Comment: No that's not another topic. The first one is ranges do simply not work for Maven plugins as I wrote before. The oracle docs assume the versions are compared as strings (Maven2) which is wrong. Overwriting the plugin versions can simply being done by using a pluginManagement entry.  A spring boot BOM does NOT define the plugins it only defines the dependencies for spring boot framework.. You seemed to misunderstand the concepts of BOM's ... and it's intention...